# what is the difference between difftime and '-'?

Tags: c, time-t

I have 2 variables of type time_t - varEnd and varStart.
Now in order to see the difference between them
Either I can do

```
varEnd - varStart;
```

or

```
difftime(varEnd, varStart);
```

and both returns number of seconds.

Please let me know, if they have any difference? or which is the recommended one?

Comment: Why is this tagged as `C++` ?

Comment: @PaulR: `difftime()` exists in both C and C++.

Comment: Well you can probably call it form Pascal or FORTRAN too, but it doesn't make this a Pascal or FORTRAN question. ;)

Comment: Probably we should add more tags, if the function can directly be called from many other languages and relavent to that community deleveoper rather than removing them, because it increases the search probability and helps that community as well.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The language specifies that `time_t` is an arithmetic type capable of representing times. It doesn't require it to represent times in any particular way.

If `time_t` represents time as the number of seconds since some moment, the `-` operator will correctly compute the difference in seconds between two `time_t` values.

If it doesn't (say, if the granularity is one millisecond, or if the bits of a `time_t` are divided into groups representing years, months, days, etc.), then the `-` operator can yield meaningless results.

The [`difftime()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/difftime) function, on the other hand, "knows" how a `time_t` represents a time, and uses that information to compute the difference in seconds.

On most implementations, simple subtraction and `difftime()` happen to do the same thing -- but only `difftime()` is guaranteed to work correctly on *all* implementations.

Another difference: `difftime()` returns a result of the floating-point type `double`, while `"-"` on `time_t` values yields a result of type `time_t`. In most cases the result will be implicitly converted to the type of whatever you assign it to, but if `time_t` happens to be an unsigned integer type, subtraction of a later time from an earlier time will yield a very large value rather than a negative value. Every system I've seen implements `time_t` as a 32-bit or 64-bit signed integer type, but using an unsigned type is permitted -- one more reason that simple subtraction of `time_t` values isn't necessary meaningful.

Answer (score 2):

difftime() returns a floating point double, just subtracting them doesn't unless you cast them  to double first.
source: [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/time_t/)

Comment: Yes, but even converting both `time_t` operands to `double` before subtracting them isn't guaranteed to do the same thing as `difftime` -- which is why `difftime` exists.  See my answer.