# how to add seconds to current time in c?

Tags: c, time

I am writing a code in c and I need to add milliseconds to the current time given by :

```
current_time = time(NULL);
loc_time=localtime(&current_time);
```

Say the local time is 20:00:00:10. I want to adding 10 seconds and display it so it displays 20:00:00:20. I am fairly new to c so any help is much appreciated. 
I am confused as time is in int format and, to add milli seconds I will have to add .001 seconds to the current second which is not an int.

Answer (score 5):

`time_t` is just an integer in seconds, so you simply add 10 to it:

```
time_wanted = time(NULL) + 10;
loc_time=localtime(&time_wanted);
```

Comment: In most cases you're right but it's implementation defined. It's a floating or an integer type. But also that sais nothing about the internal bit representation of the `time_t` type, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25198359/8051589 and here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13855956/8051589.

Comment: @AndreKampling: While the spec allows it to be a floating point type, I'm not aware of any system where it is.  But it actually doesn't matter -- either way you can do arithmetic on it.

Answer (score 0):

Since [`time()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/time) *"returns the time as the number of seconds since the Epoch, 1970-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 (UTC)."*, all you need to do is just add `10` to its return value:

```
time_t timeNow;
struct tm* time_info;
time(&timeNow);
time_info = localtime(&timeNow);
char timeStr[sizeof"HH:MM:SS"];
strftime(timeStr, sizeof(timeStr), "%H:%M:%S", time_info);
printf("Time now: %s\n", timeStr);

// add 10 seconds:
timeNow += 10;
time_info = localtime(&timeNow);
strftime(timeStr, sizeof(timeStr), "%H:%M:%S", time_info);
printf("New time: %s\n", timeStr);
```

See [full example](http://ideone.com/yS7FwM)

Answer (score -1):

`time` returns the time in seconds, so you could simply add as in

```
time_t soon = current_time + 10;
```

Comment: Sorry I posted the question wrong, I need to add milli seconds.

Comment: What platform are you on, is it Windows or some UNIX. `time` does not tell you milliseconds.