# What purpose does os.difftime(t2, t1) serve that is not covered by t2 - t1?

Tags: datetime, lua

In this code

```
t1 = os.time()
do_something_slow()
t2 = os.time()

elapsed_diff = os.difftime(t2, t1)
elapsed_sub  = t2 - t1
```

Under what circumstances will `elapsed_diff` be different to `elapsed_sub`?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13855890/what-is-the-difference-between-difftime-and.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In non-Posix systems, there is no guarantee that the values returned by `os.time` can be subtracted directly.

> In the GNU C Library, you can simply subtract time_t values. But on other systems, the time_t data type might use some other encoding where subtraction doesn't work directly. [[1](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Elapsed-Time.html)]