# Why does difftime() return a double?

Tags: c, posix

From [difftime()'s man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/difftime.3.html):

> `double difftime(time_t time1, time_t time0);`
>
> The `difftime()` function returns the number of seconds elapsed between
>   time `time1` and time `time0`, represented as a `double`.

Since 'number of seconds' doesn't require floating-point numbers, why does this function return a `double`?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13855890/827263

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/difftime) is more clear on the point:

> On POSIX systems, time_t is measured in seconds, and difftime is equivalent to arithmetic subtraction, but C and C++ allow fractional units for time_t.

Although [POSIX requires `time_t` to be an integer type](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/sys_types.h.html), for non-POSIX systems it is possible that this can return fractional seconds.

Comment: The standard says time_t can be: `Arithmetic (until C11) Real (since C11) type capable of representing times`.

Comment: @user3490458: Yes, but POSIX specifically requires `time_t` to be an integer type. http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/sys_types.h.html

Comment: Yes, but you didn't *quite* make that point explicitly. An implementation could define `time_t` as `double` and still measure time in seconds. POSIX doesn't permit that, but you didn't say so.

Comment: @KeithThompson The question is tagged `posix`... I just assumed that was the frame of reference that we were working in (ie: the question is only puzzling if we're starting from the notion that `time_t` is an integer...otherwise, why would OP be confused?)

Comment: Here's my point. POSIX requires `time_t` to be an integer type, which is relevant to the question. But your answer doesn't actually say that. It says that `time_t` is measured in seconds, but that's consistent with POSIX permitting `time_t` to be a floating-point type.

Answer (score 4):

C allows for various scalar numbers (integers, floating point) to represent time.  It needs to be a "... real types capable of representing times" C11 §7.27.1 3,

> The range and precision of times representable in `clock_t and time_t` are
>   implementation-defined. C11dr §7.27.1 4

The difference between 2 `time_t` values, as a `double` affords a vary wide range and precision.

> OP, "Since 'number of seconds' doesn't require floating-point numbers, why does this function return a double?

---

[Edit] Linux/posix might not use fractions of seconds, but other systems have done so.  The C standard that defines `difftime()` choose `double` and that accommodates an integer accumulation of seconds as well as other OS implementations.